# Is SQL server the best DB for Storing and comparing images in database for a small ecommerce application

Tags: .net, sql-server, image, postgresql

I have been trying to create a small e-commerce web based application using MS Dot Net framework.
The application will let the user allow to store the image of their product that they want to sell or purchase, then they will have the option to upload the image of a particular product and compare that image with the similar images in the database.
So my two main concerns are:
- Is MS SQL a good option to store and compare the images.
- Is the any other better database that can do the same work with less complexity of work 
  and that is also easy to integrate with MS dot net framework.

Answer (score 2):

The integration of MS SQL and Visual Studio is very good, better than any other database, so for that matter you are right to use MS SQL.

However the solution to store binary files in a database is a subject which has advantages and disadvantages, you could read:
http://www.childofthemachine.com/blog/2008/02/image-storage-database-blob-vs-file-system/

Or search the forums, there is a lot written about this subject.

Also: SQL Server can also provide another option using FILESTREAM:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the images, you may be better off storing them in the filesystem and only retaining a reference to the file location in the database.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) discussion for more information.

Comment: totally agree, let the filesystems do the job they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 also supports [FILESTREAM Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx).  Could be a good way to manage images while taking advantage of the file system's ability to manage files.